# Windows Powershell: Get Items from directory -> md5 them -> sort list by filename -> out to file

Tags: powershell, sorting, md5

Is there the way to complete mimic this unux command entirely by Windows Poweshell means, not with using the WSL:

```
find ./<dir1>/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -k 2 > dir1_hashes.md
```

I need compare two big directories on local(windows) and remote(macos) machine, but somehow I can't get it as on windows I'm always getting a list of hashes sorted different way than unix sort performs.

upd: results after harrymc version was applied:

mac machine: `md5deep -rl ./untitled | sort -k 2`

```
18abf3022eb572c21dc8d409b815424f  ./untitled/140301_114703.dng
22b2f3f71d7d18df04a4538ce6e9d771  ./untitled/140301_125241.dng
45d14f611dc31842b9c508668416cc58  ./untitled/140301_171617.dng
9239cbbce1090ec1e29de8b3ef1766af  ./untitled/140301_172922.dng
a54610821d408e1e0602f3c1c819ff3d  ./untitled/171118_203747.NEF
89aa63b14f023899d434bbd6a240af49  ./untitled/171118_203747.xmp
7ae0266bbe3575995b54a9cb85f922a5  ./untitled/171118_203919.NEF
fd5ace6d3932ddf262f54d5cac3141f9  ./untitled/171118_203919.xmp
9e9c73648c25d3beaff7da5d3842a375  ./untitled/171118_203949-2.jpg
8a8af2f9f7f657318dd7652a9dfdb686  ./untitled/171118_203949.NEF
8bb798f91842ae2f30bf39faf2ca36af  ./untitled/171118_203949.jpg
3a72150749645d7a115acb1ac5661159  ./untitled/171118_203949.xmp
8af598488c25a626a02bdb4b9a84fbe6  ./untitled/171118_204022.NEF
a2b71a1a77f6b0a6604dc91cdec94386  ./untitled/171118_204022.xmp
3798d51ee99b65ff9d3b96c3d0636ebf  ./untitled/171118_204349.xmp
777ae717eb3c4840ab5c9fef81bbe92a  ./untitled/171118_204617-2.jpg
```

windows machine: `Get-ChildItem "./untitled" -Recurse -Force -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm md5 | Sort-Object -Property 'Path' | Select-Object -Property Hash, Path`

```
Hash                             Path
----                             ----
18ABF3022EB572C21DC8D409B815424F E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_114703.dng
22B2F3F71D7D18DF04A4538CE6E9D771 E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_125241.dng
45D14F611DC31842B9C508668416CC58 E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_171617.dng
9239CBBCE1090EC1E29DE8B3EF1766AF E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_172922.dng
A54610821D408E1E0602F3C1C819FF3D E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203747.NEF
89AA63B14F023899D434BBD6A240AF49 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203747.xmp
7AE0266BBE3575995B54A9CB85F922A5 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203919.NEF
FD5ACE6D3932DDF262F54D5CAC3141F9 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203919.xmp
8BB798F91842AE2F30BF39FAF2CA36AF E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949.jpg
8A8AF2F9F7F657318DD7652A9DFDB686 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949.NEF
3A72150749645D7A115ACB1AC5661159 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949.xmp
9E9C73648C25D3BEAFF7DA5D3842A375 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949-2.jpg
8AF598488C25A626A02BDB4B9A84FBE6 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204022.NEF
A2B71A1A77F6B0A6604DC91CDEC94386 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204022.xmp
3798D51EE99B65FF9D3B96C3D0636EBF E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204349.xmp
777AE717EB3C4840AB5C9FEF81BBE92A E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204617-2.jpg
```

You can note that when file names are same the sort algorithms are working differently.

another windows version:  `Get-FileHash "./untitled/*" -Algorithm md5 | Sort-Object -Property 'Path' | Select-Object -Property Hash, Path`

But sort results are same:

```
Hash                             Path
----                             ----
18ABF3022EB572C21DC8D409B815424F E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_114703.dng
22B2F3F71D7D18DF04A4538CE6E9D771 E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_125241.dng
45D14F611DC31842B9C508668416CC58 E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_171617.dng
9239CBBCE1090EC1E29DE8B3EF1766AF E:\TEMP\untitled\140301_172922.dng
A54610821D408E1E0602F3C1C819FF3D E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203747.NEF
89AA63B14F023899D434BBD6A240AF49 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203747.xmp
7AE0266BBE3575995B54A9CB85F922A5 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203919.NEF
FD5ACE6D3932DDF262F54D5CAC3141F9 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203919.xmp
8BB798F91842AE2F30BF39FAF2CA36AF E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949.jpg
8A8AF2F9F7F657318DD7652A9DFDB686 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949.NEF
3A72150749645D7A115ACB1AC5661159 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949.xmp
9E9C73648C25D3BEAFF7DA5D3842A375 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_203949-2.jpg
8AF598488C25A626A02BDB4B9A84FBE6 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204022.NEF
A2B71A1A77F6B0A6604DC91CDEC94386 E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204022.xmp
3798D51EE99B65FF9D3B96C3D0636EBF E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204349.xmp
777AE717EB3C4840AB5C9FEF81BBE92A E:\TEMP\untitled\171118_204617-2.jpg
```

upd2:
Anyway it come obviously that I won't be able to diff files as Get-FileHash object gives me formatted different format. Well, I will use md5deep64 on windows machine and format will be the same, I have it. But anyway the culprit is the windows sort. Firstly, now I dont't know how to get it sort by second column (filepath), but seems we will be able to resolve it, but secondly, I have no idea how to get windows sort handle same filenames the same way as unix sort does. And I still have no idea how to get rid of it now.

Comment: I could achieve this working Get-ChildItem "./untitled" -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm md5  but at first I couldn't get md5deep64 working instead (as I use md5deep on mac machine). Now md5deep64 after pipe reads just the first line of the list and no more.

Comment: And anyway whether I use Get-FileHash or md5deep64, doesn't matter these both calculate same, but  this part "| sort -k 2 > dir1_hashes.md"  is actually most important as results of find or Get-ChildItems quite differ from time to time or from folder to folder. And now I have no idea how to sort output of md5 by filename before writing to file. Of course would be appreciate much if someone tell me the whole lines, variants, if there exist, so I could learn, compare and choose more appropriate for different use cases. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\path\input-folder" -Recurse -Force -File | 
  Get-FileHash | 
  Sort-Object -Property 'Path' |
  Select-Object -Property Path,Hash | Out-File "C:\path\outputfile.txt
```

References :

- [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Out-File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Get-FileHash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Sort-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Thanks harrymc ! Tried it.. But unfortunately sort is still differ. it get obvious when it run across files with the same name but different extension. Obviously algorithms of resolving this case differ from unix and windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# Get screen output  
$(cd "E:\TEMP\untitled\" ; gci . *.* -re | Get-FileHash -Algorithm md5) | % { Write-Host $(($_.hash).ToLower()+"  "+('.'+($_.Path).replace("\","/").Substring(7)))}

# Save output to file
$(cd "E:\TEMP\untitled\" ; gci . *.* -re | Get-FileHash -Algorithm md5) | % { $str=$(($_.hash).ToLower()+"  "+('.'+($_.Path).replace("\","/").Substring(7))) ; $str >>.\outputfile.txt }
```

- Outputs:

```
0a4185ca0a4a6352417d92bb14f7db2b  ./untitled/140301_114703.dng
38d5fbe2ca5d5bcf0290ba97fd232b5f  ./untitled/140301_125241.dng
0d460302f696d59ea133bd77c95f130c  ./untitled/140301_171617.dng
e2bef7514db1a33da1e29471a1b4c144  ./untitled/140301_172922.dng
3ed6937c8e0629ddec75c17282e06879  ./untitled/171118_203747.NEF
0d8fc91bbbac11d099cfcba989494307  ./untitled/171118_203747.xmp
3f394ba590f8820625e3ce29bb944510  ./untitled/171118_203919.NEF
6a993d3c75acb92e85c1fd72d3792724  ./untitled/171118_203919.xmp
21b23631620ec10feefe4f149e518357  ./untitled/171118_203949-2.jpg
bc462e2f6738546c7319de05707055d9  ./untitled/171118_203949.jpg
14420b9271c7e697f64050767ed1ca29  ./untitled/171118_203949.NEF
51bdec0fc7fc957d6ea203ea60a41bcb  ./untitled/171118_203949.xmp
35ae5d18b7bb6fbee5ef7deccb47b69d  ./untitled/171118_204022.NEF
df64b52d65d8fd83e60abb7b89790b3a  ./untitled/171118_204022.xmp
d84e53c2486cd713f0da23368a1e3cfa  ./untitled/171118_204349.xmp
22c3f84432dc90ad5261b1ceef98fc24  ./untitled/171118_204617-2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you require without any `Substring` magic. The important parts are:

- `-Culture en-US-POSIX` sorts names using a specified culture (see `Get-Culture -ListAvailable` and select the one that matches your macOS),
- Hash and file path are returned as a single string and are separated by TAB character (`` `t ``), you can change it to whatever is required in case single TAB is not enough,
- Hash is converted to lower case to match `md5sum`,
- `Resolve-Path` command converts absolute path to relative to current directory,
- `Replace` changes Windows path separator chars to *nix,
- By not using `Select-Object` we don't have the unnecessary property header and separator lines.

It works in both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7 (tried in 7.4.1).

```
cd C:\
Get-ChildItem ./Windows/System32/Com -File | `
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | `
Sort-Object -Property Path -Culture en-US-POSIX | `
% { "$($_.Hash.ToLower())`t$((Resolve-Path -Relative $_.Path).Replace('\', '/'))" }

05ed9d45b0368c5b6cb9f3fd3835d13e        ./Windows/System32/Com/comadmin.dll
00ab67c41039ee2c7ecc1cdb6eb39a7c        ./Windows/System32/Com/comempty.dat
920731b00424e33934ad8bb4a923cfe1        ./Windows/System32/Com/comrepl.exe
86b96422a58603b6419c1b8173241fed        ./Windows/System32/Com/MigRegDB.exe
d06cd0b0424c877a3ea93ed42130d5ee        ./Windows/System32/Com/mtsadmin.tlb
```